# Not able to cordova plugins add

Tags: cordova, plugins, zbar

After `corvoda init`, I run `cordova plugins add org.cloudsky.cordovaplugins.zbar`,But get error `Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/org.cloudsky.cordovaplugins.zbar`.

What's the problem?

And how Can I add plugin `org.cloudsky.cordovaplugins.zbar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Manually download zip from [link](https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar)
2. cd to your project folder
3. `cordova plugin add /path/to/plugin/directory` this will install plugin from folder downloaded from git.

Alternatively you can install directly from repo.

1. `cordova plugin add link/to/repo`

Regards

Comment: I use `cordova plugin add https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar.git `, which also works.

Comment: @Ron I do appreciate the answer but its not the clean one. Its just one way of getting it installed but not the best.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and straight forward approach is to use the following the command as mentioned in [ZBar Barcode Scanner Plugin official github page](https://github.com/tjwoon/csZBar):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-cszbar
```